What kind of mathematical objects are quarks?
Quarks are fermions and thus have spin 1/2. As a result they must have two spinor indices $s$. If the gauge group has dimension > 1 then the quark also has a color index $c$ equal to the dimension of the vector space on which the fundamental representation of the gauge group acts on. Putting this together we can explicitly write the indices of a quark field $\psi$ as $\psi^c_s$(x).
I am interested in what kind of mathematical object $\psi^c_s(x)$ is. I suspect it should be the tensor field $\psi: \mathbb{R}^{1,3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^m$ where $n$ is the dimension of the chosen representation of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ and $m$ is the dimension of the representation of the gauge group. If we denote the gauge group by $G$ then $\psi$ is equipped with a representation of $SL(2, \mathbb{C}) \times G$ (more specifically the representation of $G$ is the fundamental representation).
This seems rather straightforward but I have not seen this explicitly mentioned anywhere. Is this the mathematical definition of a (classical) quark field?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplet#Examples

two spinor indices $s$ How is $s$ “two spinor indices”?

@Ghoster You're right I was a little sloppy with my wording.

Another way to look at it this:
$\Psi$ is an associated field corresponding to a complex representation $\Delta$ of the combined gauge group $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C) \times G$. In QCD we have $G := \operatorname{SU}(3)$.
The gauge connection consist of a $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C)\cong \mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ part $\omega$ and a $\mathfrak g$ part $A$.
Let's focus on the Weyl spinor representation
For a change in of gauge $(S, \varphi): \mathcal M \to \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb C) \times G$ the gauge transformations reads as
$$\psi^a \to \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a} S \psi^a$$
$$ \omega_\mu \to S \omega_\mu S^{-1} + S \partial_\mu S^{-1}$$
and
$$ A_\mu{}^{a}{}_{b} \to \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{a} \varphi^{-1}{}^b{}_{\tilde b} A_\mu{}^{a}{}_{b} + \varphi^{\tilde a}{}_{c} \partial_\mu\varphi^{-1}{}^c{}_{\tilde b}\,.
$$
The gauge covariant derivative is given by
$$D_\mu \psi^a = \partial_\mu \psi^a + \omega_\mu \psi^a + A_\mu{}^{a}{}_{b} \psi^b$$.
The reason why the spin part of the gauge covariant derivative is usually not visible is that in flat Minkowski spacetime, there is always a gauge in which $\omega_\mu = 0$.

It may be just me, but I thought one uses rather $\mathfrak{sl}^\mathbb{C}(2,\mathbb{C}) \simeq \mathfrak{so}(4)$ as algebra. That is to say, the complexification of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ to have Dirac bi-spinors.
